# Dockerfile is not working properly when using WORKDIR command?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Here's my Dockerfile that I want to use for one of my web-api using python fastapi, but whenever I try to built it, I am getting the below given error.

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get autoclean && \
    apt-get install -y gcc make apt-transport-https ca-certificates build-essential

RUN apt-get install -y curl autoconf automake libtool pkg-config git
RUN git clone https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal

WORKDIR /libpostal
RUN ./bootstrap.sh
RUN libpostal/configure --datadir=/opt
RUN libpostal/make -j $(nproc)
RUN libpostal/make install && ldconfig



ENV PORT 8000
ENV APP_MODULE app.parser:app
ENV LOG_LEVEL debug
ENV WEB_CONCURRENCY 2

COPY ./requirements/base.txt ./requirements/base.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements/base.txt


COPY ./app /app/app
```

Whenever I run this I am getting this below error,

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.262GB
Step 1/18 : FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.8
 ---> 524e010ef786
Step 2/18 : ENV ENVIRONMENT staging
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d3e496ea9bbe
Step 3/18 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get upgrade -y &&     apt-get dist-upgrade -y &&     apt-get autoremove -y &&     apt-get clean &&     apt-get autoclean &&     apt-get install -y gcc make apt-transport-https ca-certificates build-essential
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cf3c1a8556e0
Step 4/18 : RUN apt-get install -y curl autoconf automake libtool pkg-config git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 77879c6f66e9
Step 5/18 : RUN git clone https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f1f7cf06e398
Step 6/18 : WORKDIR /libpostal
 ---> Running in 51191c3a69cb
Removing intermediate container 51191c3a69cb
 ---> d98ff97331db
Step 7/18 : RUN ./bootstrap.sh
 ---> Running in 40fd37f4900b
/bin/sh: 1: ./bootstrap.sh: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ./bootstrap.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong in the Dockerfile?

Comment: What puts `bootstrap.sh` in `/libpostal`?

Comment: @kichik Git clone, clones the repo libpostal and inside it we will have the file bootstrap.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `WORKDIR` for your base image tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.8 is `/app`. I believe [this](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-docker/blob/master/docker-images/python3.8.dockerfile#L16) is the Dockerfile for the base. When you cloned the repo, you were actually running it in `/app`.

You can explicitly set `WORKDIR /` or specify `WORKDIR /app/libpostal` to successfully run the bootstrap script.

You should also adjust your paths in the `RUN` commands after cloning since they should be relative. Here are the changes I suggest:

**Option 1**

```
# this command is run in the /app folder, a default set in the base image
RUN git clone https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal

WORKDIR /app/libpostal
RUN ./bootstrap.sh
RUN ./configure --datadir=/opt
RUN make -j $(nproc)
RUN make install && ldconfig
```

**Option 2**

```
# explicitly set working directory in root
WORKDIR /
RUN git clone https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal

WORKDIR /libpostal
RUN ./bootstrap.sh
RUN ./configure --datadir=/opt
RUN make -j $(nproc)
RUN make install && ldconfig
```